# can FB.login() display as page for facebook iframe application?

Tags: javascript, facebook

here is my code?

```
FB.login(function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                        if(response.session){
                            connectFacebook();
                        }
                    },{perms:'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
```

I need to permission user to use my application.

The problem is FB.login show in popup style but i need it to show in page style like :

[image]

how can i do it? how do i change my code?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want popup you will have to go with Facebook OAuth 2.0 for web apps. Read about it here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/