# FB.login() is opening a popup rather than an overlay

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

`FB.login` used to open a nice Facebook UI overlay. Now it opens a window popup. Is it something I can control within the code?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(r1)
{
    if(r1.authResponse === null)
    {
        FB.login(function(r2)
        {
            if(r2.authResponse !== null)
            {
                ay.fn.authorize(r2.authResponse);
            }
        });             
    }
    else
    {           
        ay.fn.authorize(r1.authResponse);
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that *FB.login* opened in an iframe? (that overlay)
I'm pretty sure that it always, or at least lately, used a popup.
The *FB.ui* dialogs do open like that, but not the login.

As it says in the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.

Comment: Yes I am sure. This started only yesterday. At first I thought it is a temporary glitch, but now it has been for a while like this.

Comment: But the documentation clearly states "... open a popup window", and it says that for a while.

Comment: Just a proof that I am not going crazy. http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-8CHDMApYAAo/TlDC7_XLN3I/AAAAAAAAAAw/qDvJF6qcX5Q/s1600/Screen+shot+2011-08-21+at+PM+04.32.59.png

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Is there `FB.ui` method that I could use to authorize user?

Comment: Weird. I don't remember seeing any iframe implementation of the login. I believe that it's due to security reasons, and that even if you load the auth dialog in an iframe facebook checks that the top frame is in facebook domain. Here's another thread about this saying the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644512/can-fb-login-display-as-page-for-facebook-iframe-application. I really don't think that it's possible to do it without a popup, but if you can think of an example for that, I'll be glad to take a look.